# VS newbie: how to use this WSDL in C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, soap, wsdl

I've added the ASMX URL to the Add Service Reference in Visual Studio.

Tried to create an object with the operation I'm looking to do:

```
  AutomationServices.ExecuteJob2Request inValue = new AutomationServices.ExecuteJob2Request();
  inValue.Body = new AutomationServices.ExecuteJob2RequestBody();
  inValue.Body.jobXml = xml.ToString();
```

But nothing happens. There are lots of classes. Not sure what ones to call. Here is the WSDL:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="urn:tibco:spotfire.dxp.automation" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" targetNamespace="urn:tibco:spotfire.dxp.automation" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
- <wsdl:types>
- <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:tibco:spotfire.dxp.automation">
- <s:element name="ExecuteJob">
- <s:complexType>
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="jobXml" type="s:string" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
- <s:element name="ExecuteJobResponse">
- <s:complexType>
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ExecuteJobResult" type="s:string" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
- <s:element name="LaunchJob">
- <s:complexType>
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="jobXml" type="s:string" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
- <s:element name="LaunchJobResponse">
- <s:complexType>
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="LaunchJobResult" type="s:string" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
- <s:element name="ExecuteJob2">
- <s:complexType>
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="jobXml" type="s:string" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
- <s:element name="ExecuteJob2Response">
- <s:complexType>
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ExecuteJob2Result" type="tns:ExecutionStatus" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
- <s:complexType name="ExecutionStatus">
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Status" type="tns:StatusCode" /> 
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Message" type="s:string" /> 
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="JobId" type="s:string" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
- <s:simpleType name="StatusCode">
- <s:restriction base="s:string">
  <s:enumeration value="InProgress" /> 
  <s:enumeration value="Finished" /> 
  <s:enumeration value="Failed" /> 
  <s:enumeration value="Missing" /> 
  <s:enumeration value="NotSet" /> 
  </s:restriction>
  </s:simpleType>
- <s:element name="LaunchJob2">
- <s:complexType>
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="jobXml" type="s:string" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
- <s:element name="LaunchJob2Response">
- <s:complexType>
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="LaunchJob2Result" type="tns:ExecutionStatus" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
- <s:element name="GetStatus">
- <s:complexType>
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="jobId" type="s:string" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
- <s:element name="GetStatusResponse">
- <s:complexType>
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetStatusResult" type="tns:ExecutionStatus" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
- <wsdl:message name="ExecuteJobSoapIn">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ExecuteJob" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="ExecuteJobSoapOut">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ExecuteJobResponse" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="LaunchJobSoapIn">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:LaunchJob" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="LaunchJobSoapOut">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:LaunchJobResponse" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="ExecuteJob2SoapIn">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ExecuteJob2" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="ExecuteJob2SoapOut">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ExecuteJob2Response" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="LaunchJob2SoapIn">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:LaunchJob2" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="LaunchJob2SoapOut">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:LaunchJob2Response" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="GetStatusSoapIn">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetStatus" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="GetStatusSoapOut">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetStatusResponse" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:portType name="JobExecutorSoap">
- <wsdl:operation name="ExecuteJob">
  <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">This method has been deprecated. Please use ExecuteJob2. Executes a job synchronously and returns the status in a parseable string format</wsdl:documentation> 
  <wsdl:input message="tns:ExecuteJobSoapIn" /> 
  <wsdl:output message="tns:ExecuteJobSoapOut" /> 
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="LaunchJob">
  <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">This method has been deprecated. Please use LaunchJob2. Starts executing a job and returns an URL you can use to check the status of the job</wsdl:documentation> 
  <wsdl:input message="tns:LaunchJobSoapIn" /> 
  <wsdl:output message="tns:LaunchJobSoapOut" /> 
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="ExecuteJob2">
  <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Executes a job synchronously and returns the status of the job.</wsdl:documentation> 
  <wsdl:input message="tns:ExecuteJob2SoapIn" /> 
  <wsdl:output message="tns:ExecuteJob2SoapOut" /> 
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="LaunchJob2">
  <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Starts executing a job and returns the id of the job, use GetStatus to check the status of the job.</wsdl:documentation> 
  <wsdl:input message="tns:LaunchJob2SoapIn" /> 
  <wsdl:output message="tns:LaunchJob2SoapOut" /> 
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="GetStatus">
  <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Get the status of a job created with LaunchJob2.</wsdl:documentation> 
  <wsdl:input message="tns:GetStatusSoapIn" /> 
  <wsdl:output message="tns:GetStatusSoapOut" /> 
  </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
- <wsdl:binding name="JobExecutorSoap" type="tns:JobExecutorSoap">
  <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" /> 
- <wsdl:operation name="ExecuteJob">
  <soap:operation soapAction="urn:tibco:spotfire.dxp.automation/ExecuteJob" style="document" /> 
- <wsdl:input>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="LaunchJob">
  <soap:operation soapAction="urn:tibco:spotfire.dxp.automation/LaunchJob" style="document" /> 
- <wsdl:input>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="ExecuteJob2">
  <soap:operation soapAction="urn:tibco:spotfire.dxp.automation/ExecuteJob2" style="document" /> 
- <wsdl:input>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="LaunchJob2">
  <soap:operation soapAction="urn:tibco:spotfire.dxp.automation/LaunchJob2" style="document" /> 
- <wsdl:input>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="GetStatus">
  <soap:operation soapAction="urn:tibco:spotfire.dxp.automation/GetStatus" style="document" /> 
- <wsdl:input>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
- <wsdl:binding name="JobExecutorSoap12" type="tns:JobExecutorSoap">
  <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" /> 
- <wsdl:operation name="ExecuteJob">
  <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:tibco:spotfire.dxp.automation/ExecuteJob" style="document" /> 
- <wsdl:input>
  <soap12:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
  <soap12:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="LaunchJob">
  <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:tibco:spotfire.dxp.automation/LaunchJob" style="document" /> 
- <wsdl:input>
  <soap12:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
  <soap12:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="ExecuteJob2">
  <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:tibco:spotfire.dxp.automation/ExecuteJob2" style="document" /> 
- <wsdl:input>
  <soap12:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
  <soap12:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="LaunchJob2">
  <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:tibco:spotfire.dxp.automation/LaunchJob2" style="document" /> 
- <wsdl:input>
  <soap12:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
  <soap12:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="GetStatus">
  <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:tibco:spotfire.dxp.automation/GetStatus" style="document" /> 
- <wsdl:input>
  <soap12:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
  <soap12:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
- <wsdl:service name="JobExecutor">
- <wsdl:port name="JobExecutorSoap" binding="tns:JobExecutorSoap">
  <soap:address location="http://as-dub-webplyt-01:2851/AutomationServices/JobExecutor.asmx" /> 
  </wsdl:port>
- <wsdl:port name="JobExecutorSoap12" binding="tns:JobExecutorSoap12">
  <soap12:address location="http://as-dub-webplyt-01:2851/AutomationServices/JobExecutor.asmx" /> 
  </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
  </wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler than I thought...

```
AutomationServices.JobExecutorSoapClient job = new AutomationServices.JobExecutorSoapClient();

var result = job.LaunchJob2(xml.ToString());
```